# If a website uses XHR for all POST requests and the server checks CORS correctly, could it still be under CSRF danger?

Tags: security, post, xmlhttprequest, cors, csrf

Say that there is a website, it

1. uses XHR for all of its POST request and only POST requests could trigger write operation on the server.
2. the server also has proper CORS config, that it does not accept any request but its own

Then is it possible for this website to still be under potential danger of CSRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is unrelated to CSRF. For example, form posts are not covered by CORS. CORS is related to reading data. CSRF is writing data.

It doesn't matter if *you* only use XHR, an evil site could use a regular form post or Flash to do a CSRF against your site.

Just follow OWASP's advice and use the Synchronizer Token pattern: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens